# Problems creating an archive file using xcode 4 and cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to create an .ipa file using xcode 4 and the latest stable release of cocos2d, and I keep getting this error when I try to archive my project, in `CCAtlasNode.m`:

```
CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();
Too many arguments provided to function like macro invocations
Use of undeclared identifier NSAssert
```

Has anyone else had this issue? My project compiles just fine in the simulator. I've already asked in the cocos2d forums and no one has been able to help.

I'm using this tutorial for create an .ipa for TestFlight: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

When it gets to the part where you actually archive your file, I get a lot of compile errors that weren't there when I tested it for simulator.

Comment: I don't use cocos2d, but I'm guessing that your problem might have something to do with the `NDEBUG` or `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` preprocessor macros needing to be present (or absent). I hope this helps you get further into solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I usualy make my `ipa` files by adding binary, builded for device, ti `zip` archive, and renaming to `*.ipa`. It's a little hacky, but works.

Comment: Mine was a little more involved. I'm using this tutorial for create an .ipa for TestFlight: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/402782-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4

When it gets to the part where you actually archive your file, I get a lot of compile errors that weren't there when I tested it for simulator.